# Array in a recursive function

Tags: php, arrays

I have this recursive function in which I must use an array for memory and verification of used data, meaning, after a string has been used i would like to remember that it has been used so i will not go over that string again in the next iteration. 
The problem is after the first iteration the array is considered NULL.

So my question is this : How do i pass an array in a recursive function ? or how do i work with arrays in recursive function?

I looked this up here and though there are many similar questions none answer my one.

Note: I understand that anything that can be done with recursion can be done with a loop... yet... this is the function. And like i mentioned on the 2nd iteration the array is considered to be NULL and i get this warning:

array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in...

Here is the logic of the function:

```
// Set Vars...
$Str = 'someData';
$S_Array = array();

// initial call...
GetData($Str, $S_Array);

function GetData ($string, $array)
{
    // string manipulations code... 

    .
    .
    .
    .
    // Attempt to Store in array

    array_push($array, $string);
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        // Recursive Call... 

        GetData($val, $array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just by mistake that you have passed $arry instead of $array in the recursive call?

Comment: It's "thanks in advance". No trailing "d".

Answer (score 0):

You are using `array_push` wrong -- the order of the arguments is switched. And there's really no need to use `array_push` at all, since the same result can be achieved with

```
$array[] = $string;
```

Comment: @ivanjovanovic
sorry for the syntax mistakes, they were misleading. i just edited my code... have look once again peals at the updated code..

Comment: This was only a typo, in my full code this is placed correctly, also I updated this post so if you could kindly have a quick look once again i would be very great-full.